# Symfony returns a 404 error when .getJSON is called

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I've recently deployed my Symfony project to a production environment.
Everything is loading except the .getJSON jquery function.
This returns a 404 error. Now the strange part is that it works localy.

This is the code.

**Jquery:**

```
$.getJSON('/ClientThisYear', function(response) {
```

**Routing:**

```
app:
   resource: "@AppBundle/Controller"
   type:     annotation
```

**AppBundle/Controller:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/ClientThisYear")
 */
public function ClientThisYear()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $ClientStats = $em->getRepository('ClientBundle:Client')
        ->ClientStats();
    $ClientArray = array();
    foreach($ClientStats[0] as $Arr)
    {
        $ClientArray[] = $Arr;
    }
    $Return = json_encode($ClientArray);
    return new Response($Return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
}
```

So it worked for a while but after a while it started returning a 404 error.

**What i've tried is:**

- Clearing the cache.
- Deployed it again from local.

**Error log :**

```
[2015-12-30 14:50:43] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /ClientThisYear" (from "http://example.nl/web/admin")" at /home/**/**/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 2377 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /ClientThisYear\" (from \"http://example.nl/web/admin\") at /home/**/**/var/cache/prod/classes.php:2377, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/**/**/var/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:255)"} []
```

Can someone please help me with this

Comment: Have you tried it in dev mode?

Comment: yes i've tried it locally in the dev mode and prod mode. When i did that, there wasn't any errors and it showed the records correctly. The problem is only on the server. It is a exact copy of the local one.

Comment: Does you local path prefix match the one from production? For example `http://localhost/myapp/ClientThisYear` vs `http://mywebsite/ClientThisYear`. Can you invoke the path via browser at all? What does the log say about error? Or maybe production does not have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: It has the same path as the /admin route in the same controller. And that is shown correctly . So i think that the path is set correctly. I'll edit my question with the error log

Comment: The command - 'php app/console router:debug'  may reveal a hint

Comment: app_dash_clientthisyear   ANY  ANY  ANY  /ClientThisYear

Comment: For people with the same problem. I forgot to add the annotation method to the controller so it has to be     /**
     * @Route("/web/ClientThisYear")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */

Comment: It sounds like you might have an error in your web server configuration that is requiring the `/web` route.

Answer (score 1):

Using route in Javascript may require [FOSJsRouting](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

This bundle allow you to use your route with javascript